# How to fix this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I'm not sure how to get rid of this error. Below is my example datasets. Is there another step that I'm missing?

[image]

```
Code below: 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier 
models = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100) 
np.random.seed(42)

X = re_arrange.drop('Gender',axis=1) 
y = re_arrange['Gender']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

models.fit(X_train,y_train)
models.score(X_test, y_test)
```

Comment: `RandomForestClassifier` requires features to be numerical (`float` or `int`). `Branch` is string and cannot be converted to `float`. You should look at either categorical or one-hot-encoder.

Comment: @QuangHoang appreicate the fast response. will look into this

Answer (score 2):

Your column "Branch" has letters whereas the RandomForestClassifier expects numbers.
I believe it is of categorical type. So you can encode the column "Branch" using some categorical encoding as shown below before you do train test split

```
X["Branch"] = pd.get_dummies(X["Branch"])
```

It will map letters 'A', 'B' etc in numbers. It does not change your data but just converts them in computational-friendly state

Comment: appreicate the fast response. never knew what get_dummies was. going to play around with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

RandomForestClassifier can handle only numerical values in any of its features. As you can see, you have text/object data in almost all your features. So 1st of all:
do X.info() to know the data type of your features. If you find 'string' & 'object', encode all those features in numbers using One-Hot-Encoder or LabelEncoding.

[One-Hot-Encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

[LabelEncoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)